# Why is Mach 0.3 the threshold separating compressible and incompressible flow?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I've read that Mach 0.3 is pretty much the upper limit for treating air as an incompressible fluid.  The sources I've read seem to treat this as a given, without proof or justification.

Why is this the limit?  Is there a mathematical justification for this?  Also, does this limit only apply to air? If not, then what does the limit depend on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Wikipedia gives the reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressible_flow) for Mach 0.3 as due to the fact that this achieves ~5% change in density.

I found a [NASA page](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/machrole.html) that describes (analytically!) the relationship. I cited the source, but I'll reproduce the work here for posterity, in the event their links change.

Start with conservation of momentum:

$$
(\rho V) dV = -dp \\
$$

where $\rho$ is the fluid density, $V$ is the velocity, and $p$ is the pressure. for isentropic flow:

$$ 
\frac{dp}{p} = \gamma \frac{d\rho}{\rho} \\
dp = \left( \frac{\gamma p}{\rho} \right) d\rho \\
$$

where $\gamma$ is the specific heat ratio. The ideal gas law gives:

$$
p = \rho R T \\
$$

where $R$ is the specific gas constant and $T$ is the absolute temperature. So, substituting:

$$
dp = \gamma R T d\rho 
$$

The speed of sound can be calculated by:

$$
\gamma R T = a^2 \\
$$

where $a$ is the speed of sound, so:

$$
dp = a^2 d\rho \\
$$

Substituting the expression above into the conservation of momentum equation gives:

$$
(\rho V)dV = -a^2 d\rho \\
-\left(\frac{V^2}{a^2}\right)dV/V = d\rho/\rho \\
-M^2 dV/V = d\rho/\rho \\
$$

where $M$ is the Mach number. *This* gives a Mach number of 0.3 to be approximately a 5% change in density.

As a note, this is based on the Mach number, which in turn is dependent on the speed of sound in the gas, so it's automatically adjusted on a per-gas basis.

Comment: @Paul this is derived from the conservation of momentum. it is not so much a "rule" as a suggestion. if you don't care about 10% (or higher) changes in density (or other quantities), go ahead and use the incompressible relations for high Mach numbers. if you *do* care about small changes in density, then use the compressible relations even for low Mach numbers

Comment: It's not just density.  When we non-dimensionalize equations, we get dimensionless groups out.  The rule of thumb is that if a dimensionless group is less than 0.1 we can ignore the relevant terms.  In the case of the Mach number it shows up squared.  So we want the (Mach number)^2<0.1.  This approximately gives 0.3.  It's not just the density - basically all things that change at higher speed are going to be affected by roughly 10% once the Mach number reaches 0.3.

Comment: @Joel - For context, OP was asking about compressibility specifically, which is why this answer only covers density.

Comment: I would make it clearer that it's not a sharp dividing line. If you have a lower tolerance for errors, start using the compressible solution at lower mach numbers. If you don't care as much, keep assuming incompressibility at higher mach numbers. 10% is just an arbitrary choice of how much error "really matters", and 0.3 falls out of that mathematically, but no less arbitrarily.

Comment: @chuck - nitpicking here, but treating something as an incompressible fluid means I get to say that the divergence of the velocity field is 0.  That affects a lot more than just density - to the point that when I go to a talk and someone says he's assuming its an incompressible fluid it's usually not a statement about density.

Comment: @costrom  Of course it is!   Transition from compressible and incompressible is not a binary situation.  Fluids just get more and more parametrizable with one set of equations or another; in between states are a total mess to analyze.   Then again, "Well, Flash [Fearless], in this part of the galaxy, gravity is not so much a law as a local ordinance."

Comment: http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~devenpor/aoe3114/calc.html

Comment: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/isentrop.html